# How do you pass values from a datareader in a while loop to a method in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables in a database that I am iterating through using a SQL statement. It searches for applications that need to have contracts renewed. I use SQL date math to check whether managers need to be notified of a contract renewal. If today's date = the date in the notificationDate field, the console app should send an email to the person listed as the analyst/manager of that application. Here is my code so far:

```
namespace ContractApp
{
    class Program
    {
        //initializes strings for storing information from the table
        static string aretheyManager;
        static string listedanalystEmail;
        static string listedmanagerEmail;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int warningWindow = 10;

        try
        {
            //connects to the AppInfo_dev table in the database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=10.52.2.169\\sqlcluster,1206;uid=TannerAppsWriter;pwd=TannerAppsWriter;database=AppInfo_dev;");
            conn.Open();

            //sets up a sequal command called selectedValues
            SqlCommand selectValues = conn.CreateCommand();

            //Pulls information from three tables in the database (AppInfo_dev, SoftwareApp, IT_Personnel)
            //Takes the AppID from the Contracts list and compares it to AppID in the Apps list and displays matches
            //Then it finds employee information related to the Primary Analyst that is listed for that application
            //Adds a field called "notificationDate" that is filled by subtracting the "warningWindow" and "TerminationWindow" from the RenewalDate
            //Finds contracts listed that have a "notificationDate" that is the same as the current date
            //Takes the eMail fields and appends "@tanner.org" to the end of the text in the field
            selectValues.CommandText = "My SQL statement goes here...it works so I didn't bother posting it since it is really long"

            //Reads values in specified columns in the database
            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = selectValues.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        //Converts the values in the tables to strings
                        aretheyManager = Convert.ToString(dataReader["isManager"]);
                        listedanalystEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]);
                        listedmanagerEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //If there is an error, catch it
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void sendEmailNotification()
    {


        //Create an email to send notifying of contract termination
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        //Check to see if the listed analyst is a manager
        //If they are, send the email to them
        //If they are not, send they email to their manager.
        if (aretheyManager == "True")
        {
            message.To.Add(listedanalystEmail);
        }
        else
        {
            message.To.Add(listedmanagerEmail);
        }

        message.Subject = "This contract requires your attention!";
        message.From = new MailAddress("no response email address goes here");
        message.Body = "There is an application contract that is in need of renewal.";

        message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("client info goes here");
        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

}

The SQL statements works as expected. It iterates through the rows in the table and pulls contracts with a notificationDate = the current date. I am having trouble with the datareader. It iterates through the contracts pulled by the SQL statement, but only stores the last value it reads into the strings. I need it to store any and all values it pulls so an email gets sent to each person if there are multiple people that need to be notified.

Comment: If there is a thread on this site that you believe to be an answer to my question please let me know. I search google and this site for close to an hour and have not found anything that has worked yet so that is why I posted.

Comment: You don't have to close or dispose of dataReader, the `using {}` block takes care of that.  You also don't need the `if...HasRows` block.  If there aren't any rows, the `while {}` block will just jump to the end of the block.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have taken out the close and dispose lines.

Comment: You should use/consume the IDatareader AS QUICKLY AS POSSIBLE.  Do not "hold onto it".  As others have stated, put the values in a List<string> or other collection.  Unless you have a billion rows, then you'll need to rethink it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their assistance (suggestions/comments). I see that most of you suggested I just a list which was an idea that I had at one point until I read about passing the parameters. Again, thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your SendMail method to be more generic.
Receive parameters with the info on the people that should receive a mail

```
private void sendEmailNotification(string aretheyManager, 
                                  string listedanalystEmail, 
                                  string listedmanagerEmail)
{
    //Create an email to send notifying of contract termination
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    //Check to see if the listed analyst is a manager
    //If they are, send the email to them
    //If they are not, send they email to their manager.
    if (aretheyManager == "True")
    {
        message.To.Add(listedanalystEmail);
    }
    else
    {
        message.To.Add(listedmanagerEmail);
    }

    message.Subject = "This contract requires your attention!";
    message.From = new MailAddress("no response email address goes here");
    message.Body = "There is an application contract that is in need of renewal.";

    message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("client info goes here");
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Now in your loop while you read the data from the reader call the above method passing the appropriate values

```
    if (dataReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            //Converts the values in the tables to strings
            aretheyManager = Convert.ToString(dataReader["isManager"]);
            listedanalystEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]);
            listedmanagerEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"]);

            // For every record read, send the email
            sendEmailNotification(aretheyManager, 
                                  listedanalistEmail, 
                                  listedmanagerEmail)                        
        }
    }
```

Of course you could also store the retrieved values from the DataReader in some form of object collection (a `List<Email>` where EMail is a class that contains your three parameters) but this will lead to a double loop (one to read and one to send the emails) so, if it is not really required to store in memory all those email addresses, I suggest to send the mail while you read from your reader.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over dataSet but storing the values in string rather than some kind of list. That's why only last value is stored

```
  //create a class to hold the value
class SomeDTO
{
   public string aretheyManager;
   public string listedanalystEmail;
   public string listedmanagerEmail;
}
  //in your main
 //Reads values in specified columns in the database
            List<SomeDTO> collection = new List<SomeDTO>();
            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = selectValues.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                       SomeDTO obj = new SomeDTO();
                        //Converts the values in the tables to strings
                        obj.aretheyManager = Convert.ToString(dataReader["isManager"]);
                        obj.listedanalystEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]);
                        obj.listedmanagerEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"]);

                       collection.Add(obj);

                    }
                }
                dataReader.Close();
                dataReader.Dispose();
            }


//send email notification method
private void sendEmailNotification(List<SomeDTO> obj)
{
     //loop and send email
}
```

Comment: From what I have read, it can be done this way as long as I pass the values into the sendEmailNotification() method as it is iterating through. I am just having trouble passing the values into the method.

Comment: Yes, you could change the signature of your SendEmailNotification and pass the value directly or use the signature that i have written

Answer (score 2):

A datareader is not designed to hold data. It just iterates over data. If you want to store
 the results of the "read", add the data into an ArrayList or some other data structure that will allow you to perform further work on the data.

```
 con.Open();

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.Read()) {
        object[] values = new object[dr.FieldCount];
        dr.GetValues(values);
        al.Add(values);
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
```

Comment: I'd go with a modern "generic" instead of ArrayList (if on FW 2.0 or above.)  List<MyDtoObject>

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a `Person` class

```
public class Person
{
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
    public string AnalystEmail { get; set; }
    public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Program` class you'd need to declare a `List<Person> _personList = new List<Person>();`

Finally, in your `while loop`:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    _personList.Add(new Person {
        IsManager = Convert.ToBool(dataReader["isManager"]),
        AnalystEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]),
        ManagerEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"])
    });
}
```

After that, you could use `foreach(var person in _personList)` or the like for your emailing.

Answer (score 0):

```
       using (var reader = selectValues.ExecuteReader()) {
           return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(record => new SomeDTO {
                                  aretheyManager = Convert.ToString(record["isManager"]),
                                  listedanalystEmail = Convert.ToString(record["analystEmail"]),
                                  listedmanagerEmail = Convert.ToString(record["managerEmail"])
                               })
                        .ToList();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

no matter how manytimes you iterate over these your values will be updated each time and you will get only last updated values .
 because for each iteration you are assigning new values to your `strings`.

```
               while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    //Converts the values in the tables to strings
                    aretheyManager = Convert.ToString(dataReader["isManager"]);
                    listedanalystEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]);
                    listedmanagerEmail = Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"]);
                }
```

I think you should use some kind of collection for storing your values .

```
          List<string> aretheyManager = new List<string>(); 
          List<string> listedanalystEmail =new List<string>();  
         List<string> listedmanagerEmail = new List<string>();  


        while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                //Converts the values in the tables to strings
               aretheyManager.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["isManager"]));
               listedanalystEmail.Add( Convert.ToString(dataReader["analystEmail"]));
               listedmanagerEmail.Add(Convert.ToString(dataReader["managerEmail"]));
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a `struct` to hold all of your details and then create a `List<yourstruct>`.

Populate your `struct` within your loop.

When you drop out of your loop call your email method and pass the list.

In your email method `foreach` your list sending an email each time

Comment: An object like this should probably be a class not a struct, given that it doesn't logically represent a single value, the size of the object isn't going to be really small, value semantics aren't important for performance reasons, etc.

Comment: Yep. My bad. I still thinks of structs as being stored on the stack and not the heap although I have learned this is not the case.